# ssh connecttimeout

Tags: command-line, ssh

I couldn't find any documentation for the -oConnectTimeout option. So I was just wondering if its just for the ssh connection to occur or for the total connection? like if I have a single line command wherein I connect to a sqlserver from command line and execute a query that takes 20 seconds, then should I keep the timeout as 5 or 10 seconds for the conn to occur, or the whole 30-35 seconds for the query to be completed also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its for the time it takes to connect to the server. Although I would not recommend relying on -oConnectTimeout, I'd rather close the connection when the job is done, regardless of how long it takes. You should use this value to increase the timeout more than the default TCP timeout.